# certain keys of a notebook keyboard not giving the right characters

Tags: laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop

I just bought an Asus ZenBook UX550VD.

There are problems with the keyboard. Certain keys are not giving the correct characters.

For example: when I press the key "0" it returns the character "/". Shift + key "0" returns the character "/" as well.

In the same way the key "p" returns "*" and the key "-" returns "+".

When I press these keys together with the Function key "fn" the correct characters appear.

In Windows 10, the correct keyboard layout is selected.

The problem also occurs without Windows e.g. when I use the keys in BIOS setup.

Has anyone had a similar problem or any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Disable NUM LOCK.

Comment: The keyboard does not have a overlayed number block and no NUM LOCK.